# Problem to run a plugin to gcc in Windows 10

Tags: c++, c, gcc, gcc-plugins

Im working in Windows 10 OS. I want to run a simple gcc plugin, so first i installed Mingw. Then I compile a simple hellowrd.c and works fine. But when I tried to simulate a plugin that uses "gcc-pugin.h" include, an error ocurrs because gcc-plugin.h "no such file or directory".

Apparently the mingw installation did not install everything I need.

Is it a problem that Windows does not work?

```
#include "gcc-plugin.h"
#include "plugin-version.h"
 ...
```

Comment: This is very specific to the platform and implementation. It would probably be better asked on a Mingw forum or the like.

Answer (score 0):

That means wherever that header file is, it was not found in the default include directory. You can try typing the full path to the .h file in the #include directive.

Comment: Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) , and be sure with your answer. Better it can be a comment